# How can i forbid displaying a form field in twig from formType in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I cancel displaying form field in *twig*, if I do not need it?

```
<p>Form: <br>
            $form ->add("rxOriginCode", ChoiceType::class, [<br>
                "label"    => "Rx Origin",<br>
                "required" => true,<br>
                "choices"  => <br>PrescriptionOriginCode::getDictionary(EnumFactory::FLAG_SHORT),<br>
                "mapped"   => false,<br>
                "data"     => $data->getRx()->getRxOriginCode(),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying your elements one by one, there is a parameter in the method `form_end` to prevent Twig from generating elements you did not display yes :

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables